# How to get precision, recall, f1 score in transfer learning vgg16 model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

How to to get the precision, recall, confusion matrix, and f1 score? I am new in deep learning. Anyone give me a resource or help me to find the information.

Comment: are you using keras to use VGG16?

Answer (score 0):

Import the modules from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
```

Assuming your test set explanatory variables are contained in `X_test`, the response variables in `y_test`, and your model is named `model`, predict the values for the test set:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

And then print the classification report and confusion matrix:

```
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: @AshikulAzizSiddique Please update your question with your code and any error messages you receive.